Bubbling and cracking in ceiling - but no mold and dry to touch
I am trying to understand what this bubbling and crumbling could be from. It's all dry to the touch, it does move when I touch it - but nothing is leaking or wet as far as I can tell. There is a shower slightly to the left and above this part of the ceiling, and stairs are below the ceiling - What could this peeling and cracking and crumbling be from, who do I call, and generally how concerned should I be?
Photos


There are definite signs that water infiltrated at one time.
If the area is dry now it may have been a one time occurance, like water out of the shower or something similar. You will need to examine the shower closely. It is likely a leak there has caused this. Look for cracks near the drain and in the grout if the shower is tile. ( more detail about the shower is needed)
You will need to remove the loose plaster and neutralize any rusted areas. ( There appears to be an area at a perpendicular edge that is corner bead that has rusted.) The bubbled paint needs to be cut out and the entire area finished with plaster or drywall compound. Then sanded, primed and painted.
A drywall finisher or good handyman should be able to do this job. However it is important to have a good idea that the cause has been corrected first.
